# Use gopdf to merge multiple PDFS and size them into a single pdf

Tags: go, pdf

Now I have a requirement that I want to merge multiple pdf files and crop them to an appropriate size into one pdf. I would like to know whether gopdf v0.16.1 or other versions support importing multiple PDFS and crop them to the appropriate size. What should I do?

I tried the code on github, but I didn't seem to find the corresponding code. Has anyone done something similar? Could you please give me some suggestions and links to the corresponding documents.